# django-autocompelete-light in materialize model select2 search input not working

Tags: django, jquery-select2, materialize

I am use the django-autocomplete-light whith this [css style](https://gist.github.com/DSKonstantin/45033ba19af0471a3474e767cfc65518) in materialize .
when in  modal , the select2 search input not working,help